# Making Newly created file public on Google Cloud Storage Go runtime Client API

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-storage

Im using Google Cloud Storage Go Runtime client API to write a string from GO server into a file in the default bucket . Here is the code

```
wc := storage.NewWriter(d.ctx, bucket, fileName)
wc.ContentType = "text/plain"
if _, err := wc.Write([]byte(myData)); err != nil {
        d.errorf("createFile: unable to write data to bucket %q, file %q: %v", bucket, fileName, err)
        return
}
```

But im Not able set right ACL permissions on the ***wc*** object to make the file public ?? How to do achieve it so that the created file becomes public ?

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Try setting:

```
wc.ACL = []storage.ACLRule{{storage.AllUsers, storage.RoleReader}}
```

Alternately, you can also change the default object ACL on the bucket so that newly created objects default to being publicly readable.

Comment: I added this , Its not making the file public !

Comment: Since setting ACL on ***wc*** object didnt work , so i decided to open an issue on the github repo of Google golang-gloud repo , please take a look at the conversation , here is the link of opened issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/issues/122

Comment: What will be the solution for now?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same by this also.

```
acl := client.Bucket(bucket).Object(object).ACL()
if err := acl.Set(ctx, storage.AllUsers, storage.RoleReader); err != nil {
        return err
}
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#storage-make-object-public-go) is the link to the docs.